# How to wrapinner after the text in label using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have to wrap the span inside label element but using wrapinner working for the around the text. how to avoid it.

```
$('td.req-entry').find('label').wrapInner('<span class="asterisk_required" style="color:#ab1d29;padding-left:3px;">*</span>');
```

//output

```
<label><span class="asterisk_required" style="color:#ab1d29;padding-left:3px;">asdfasdfasdf*</span></label>
```

//Exact output

```
<label>asdfasdfasdf <span class="asterisk_required" style="color:#ab1d29;padding-left:3px;">*</span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the `*` to come after the initial label text. In that case you could just use `.append()`. You can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://jsfiddle.net/ckLjdrwb/9/

```js
$('td.req-entry').find('label').append('<span class="asterisk_required" style="color:#ab1d29;padding-left:3px;">*</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class='req-entry'>
      <label for="stuff">asdfasdfasdf</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```